# Handling Null exception with SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Not able to figure out what is the problem with following code and data. It returns "NullReferenceException was unhandled"

Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Filename1);

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("temp","http://www.Rahiman.com");

string name1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("//temp:Company/temp:Businesscard[2]/temp:Name", mgr).
    InnerText;

Console.WriteLine(name1);
```

Data File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Company     xmlns="http://www.Rahiman.com">
  <![CDATA[This data file is created as part of 1st BizTalk example]]>
  <Businesscard>
    <name> Rahiman </name>
    <Phone Category="Mobile">+91 900028xxxx</Phone>
    <Phone Category="Land">+91 40-40020xxxx</Phone>
    <Phone Category="Fax">+91 900028xxxx</Phone>
    <Email>John@Yahoo.com</Email>
  </Businesscard>
  <Businesscard>
    <name>Shaik </name>
    <Phone Category="Mobile">+91 900028xxxx</Phone>
    <Phone Category="Land">+91 40-40020xxxx</Phone>
    <Phone Category="Fax">+91 900028xxxx</Phone>
    <Email>John@Yahoo.com</Email>
  </Businesscard>
</Company >
```

I have tried

```
string name1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//temp:Company/temp:Businesscard[2]/temp:Name", mgr).
    InnerText;
```

as well

Thanks.

Comment: While I appreciate that technically all questions asking about NullRef exceptions could be marked as duplicates, the reasons why nullref may occur are many and varied and often it's that "need a second pair of eyes" aspect of the request, not necessarily the null ref itself, that is being sought. As such, directing to a generic advice (actually, like I've given in my answer) isn't going to be as helpful as eg Gilad has given as to why the null is occurring

Comment: @CaiusJard StackOverflow isn't a debugging service, however. In fact, after reading the linked duplicate, it's highly likely OP will understand *what* the error means, and *how* to debug it. If it turns out the library is incorrectly returning null, when it shouldn't, then that's an entirely different question, and could be posted as such.

Comment: I partly accept the argument, but nearly every question on this site falls into one of two categories: "how do I do X" and "here's my broken solution to how to do X, please help fix it". In the case of the former, the questioner gets hammered for not putting any effort in, and maybe that's fair. In the case of the latter, we can't start hammering them with the "we do not exist to debug your code" stick; everyone needs a little help understanding the complexities of compiler and runtime error messages at some point in their early career and sometimes the cause is so subtle it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 3):

When retrieving the `Name` tag it is case sensitive so it should be `name`

```
"//temp:Company/temp:Businesscard[2]/temp:name"
```

You can also use the `?.` null propagation:

```
string name1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("//temp:Company/temp:Businesscard[2]/temp:name", mgr)?.InnerText;
```

Comment: Note, of course, that we aren't certain he uses c# 6, but it's a handy tip if he does and hasn't come across the syntax before. For more info on it google "c# 6 null propagation". (I wasn't the downvorer; I think your advice is excellent here, so I've no problem cancelling out that dv with an uv. Let's see if there's any feedback from the dver)

Comment: @CaiusJard - true but in any case the problem isn't the accessing of the inner text at all but the xpath used - the `name` vs `Name`

Comment: `but indexes start from 0`... no, this is an xpath query, indices are 1-based.

Comment: @JeffMercado - sorry :) corrected. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The xml in the question also appears not well formed at the end node..

Comment: @CaiusJard - true but that is probably a typo of when posting because if it was that the exception was different (tried it :) )

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. It is very bad on my part I missed simple point  case sensitive "Name" vs. "name".

Comment: @RahimanS - That's ok :) If this helped you solve it please consider marking question as solved by the answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can't be that `doc` is null, so it must be hat the result of the `SelectSingleNode` method call is null. Don't refer to the `.InnerText`
property until you're sure it isn't null:

```
string name1;
var n = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//temp:Company/temp:Businesscard[2]/temp:Name", mgr);
if(n!=null)
  name1 = n.InnerText;
```